# DFA that accepts a*b*c*

Tags: finite-automata

Beginner in DFA related studies, was trying to figure out how to create a DFA with {a,b,c}, that can recognize a * b * c *.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: This is a very basic question. I suggest trying to construct a DFA for simpler languages, such as $a^*$ and $a^*b^*$, and then tackle $a^*b^*c^*$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible DFA:

[image]

Basically, just send any invalid string like baa*c*, caa*, etc. to a junk state.

As suggested by Yuval Filmus, you can minimize the number of states further by merging $s$ and $a$ :

[image]

Comment: The states $s$ and $a$ can be identified.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry, but what do you mean by 'identify'

Comment: You can merge them.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I merged the states. Is this DFA what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, this is the minimal DFA.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have done the job
[image: This seemed to have done the job]

Comment: It is a working **NFA**; to make it a DFA, you have to specify all possible transitions from any state

Comment: Some people allow the transition function of a DFA to be partial.

Comment: States A and B can be identified.

Comment: It would help other people with the same problem if you explained _why_ this works, rather than just stating it as fact.